# javascript find index of matched value in ay array of objects

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for the index of an item in an array of a list of objects by looking for a specific value inside of an object

currently, I'm doing this via

```
var x = [{ _id: '59974d9015a07e09b88e3b53', status: '1', id: '59974d2915a07e09b88e3b4b' }, { _id: '12345', status: '1', id: '54321' }]

var index = null;

for (var i=0; i<x.length; i++) {
    if ( x[i]._id == '59974d9015a07e09b88e3b53' ) {
        index = i;
        break;
    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/yaocpsjd/

is there a more elegant solution via ES* where I wouldn't need to do a loop?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`findIndex()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) method that returns index of first element that satisfies condition otherwise it returns -1.

```js
var x = [{
  _id: '59974d9015a07e09b88e3b53',
  status: '1',
  id: '59974d2915a07e09b88e3b4b'
}, {
  _id: '12345',
  status: '1',
  id: '54321'
}]


var index = x.findIndex(e => e._id == '59974d9015a07e09b88e3b53')
console.log(index)
```